# What's the standard practice for naming an intermediary table in SQL?

Tags: sql, naming-conventions

I have a table called Product and a table called Shop. Each shop has a list of Products that it sells. I need an intermediate table that has ShopID and ProductID in it. What should I call that table? My mind has drawn a blank.

ShopProducts?

Edit: Perhaps I should call it "ShopAvailableProducts"? Or is that too confusing.

Comment: dupe of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045034/whats-the-correct-name-for-a-association-table-many-to-many-relationship

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an official name for the many-to-many relationship table in a database schema?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429908/is-there-an-official-name-for-the-many-to-many-relationship-table-in-a-database-s)

Comment: @ChrisW  - May well be a dupe but that linked one is about the name of the concept not of the individual tables.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes ShopProduct (depending on the plurals you use) would be how I'd name a link entity.

```
Shop
  |
-----
| | |
ShopProduct
| | |
-----
  |
Product
```

So a shop can have many products and each product can be sold in many shops

Answer (score 1):

I prefer something along the lines of `ShopProductsJunction`. [This article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) might give a few other naming hints:

> ...also known as a cross-reference table, bridge table, join table, map table, intersection table, linking table, or link table

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ShopProducts is good enough. No problem with that

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would just use ShopProduct as it makes sense in **my language** a product for/from/asociated-with a shop.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen `product_shop_rel` used by ORMs. Like in OERP (now known as Odoo) for example.

Answer (score -1):

Shop2Product (or Product2Shop) is better: "2" in mid shows that this is intermediary table.