# What is the difference between Junction and Intermediate tables in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the difference between a Junction and an Intermediate table?

I was looking up how to create a table to handle many-to-many relationship between two tables and came across both terms.  Are they the same?

Comment: maybe dupe https://stackoverflow.com/q/1429908/73226

Comment: Personally, I use the term `association table` but `junction table` and others are also used. The term `Intermediate table` is overloaded and may refer to temp tables to store intermediate query results.

Comment: Not quite a dupe.  No mention of Intermediate tables, but I get your meaning.  Thanks, all.